# Alt-Tab notification on panels within a form

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, panel, alt-tab

I'm trying to clear some variable on a panel, for example, if I had a bool which lets me know when I'm click dragging on a panel's surface I set this to false when a MouseUp event occurs (this may or may not be correct way to do this but serves as an example).

If while click dragging I then alt-tab to another application the panel itself doesn't appear to get any notifications, like focus->leave / mouseup for example, is there something I'm missing, an event I've overlooked?

There seems to be a way of doing this by using the forms Deactivate event, which I suppose I could just call a suspend type method on my panel if I create a new Panel class, but I was wondering if something already existed that would propagate all children on a form with some notification that our form is no longer the main focus.

Comment: WinForms or WPF? (The forms tag is for HTML forms, if you want WinForms then use the WinForms tag.)

Comment: Sorry about that, it was supposed to be Winforms, I've now changed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reliably getting these kind of notifications requires that you use the Capture property.  Set it to true on the MouseDown event.  It ensures that all mouse messages are directed to your panel, even if the mouse is no longer hovering the panel.  That however still doesn't cover rude focus changes, like Alt+Tab or Alt+Esc.  You also need to implement the MouseCaptureChanged event to know when the operating system stepped in.

In general, if you are trying to implement Drag + Drop then you ought to use DoDragDrop().  When it returns you can always be sure that the drag operation is completed, for whatever reason.  The return value of the method tells you what happened.  Note that this also supports switching to another window, albeit that it is not very discoverable, you drag to the task bar button to force a switch.

Comment: It's mainly for the scrolling around of a panel rather than draging and dropping items, but the mouse capture is good to know thanks for that, for any other bits I'll just hook into the Activated/Deactivate events. Three ups now pending for you. :)